# How to keep wild turkey meat moist

Tags: soup

What some effective techniques to ensure that wild turkey legs, wings, thighs stay moist when cooking them off for soup?

Comment: I usually simmer in lightly salted water for 3 hrs.  Then I hand pick the meat and chop to size before adding it back to the broth and other ingredients. Those big old gobblers are very tough and I am looking to make the meat more tender.  Am I cooking too long, not long enough??  Should I add something, or do something to better prep??

Comment: I recommend you add this additional info to your question using the edit button and add anything else you think will he helpful as well. It definitely gives us a lot more info to go off of :D And welcome!

Comment: For your simmering, the issue is going to be what temperature the water is actually at -- you want to start it in boiling water, let it return to the boil, then let the temperature of the water drop to the temperature you need to cook the turkey to for safety (I assume 165°F), and hold it 'til the turkey is cooked through.

Comment: @KenSnyder I edited 'the best way' to 'some effective techniques' as the 'the best' can be subjective where 'effective' just asks for 'things that work well'.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a pressure cooker. This will preserve the moisture of the bird while cooking it thoroughly with the added benefit of taking significantly less time. (45 min - 1 hour depending on the size of the bird).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend brining or salting the meat and roasting it, then chopping it and adding it near the end of cooking for the soup.  Wild turkey is difficult to say the least!

The reason for my suggestion is that I make a shortcut version of chicken and dumplings that uses a rotisserie chicken from the grocery store, with the shredded meat stirred in at the very end.  Works nicely there, so adapting that to your turkey soup would just require you to roast your own turkey meat instead of cheating like I do.